# Regex to find sentences of a minimum length

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that finds sentences with a minimum length.

Really my conditions are:

1. there must at least be 5 words in a sequence
2. words in sequence *must* be distinct
3. sequence must be followed by some punctuation character.

So far I have tried

`^(\b\w*\b\s?){5,}\s?[.?!]$`

If my sample text is:

```
This is a sentence I would like to parse.

This is too short. 

Single word

Not not not distinct distinct words words.

Another sentence that I would be interested in.
```

I would like to match on strings 1 and 5.

I am using the python re library. I am using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test and it appears the regex I have above is doing quite a bit of work regards to backtracking so I imagine those knowledgable in regex may be a bit appalled (my apologies).

Comment: Not every string problem is a regex problem. I wouldn't use regexes at all. Split on punctuation to get sentences, then split sentences on whitespace to get words. Filter out sentences with too few words. Make sure words are unique, e.g. by putting them in a set and making sure the set's length is the same as the list's length. Done.

Comment: Chris you are totally right. Tunnel vision is very real. Thanks

Comment: `This is too short.` has four words and ends in a punctuation character - what’s wrong with that?

Comment: @barny You are right, that is a mistake. Edited question.

Comment: Do you mean that, given a collection of strings, you wish to determine which : 1) contain at least 5 words; 2) contain no repeated words; 3) and ends with the character `.`, `?` or `!`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes - exactly.

Comment: You may consider wording it that way, or similar, in your question, as it is more precise. "Sequence", in particular, is confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex to identify the strings that meet all three conditions:

```
^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.+\b\1\b)(?:.*\b\w+\b){5}.*[.?!]\s*$
```

with the case-indifferent flag set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RhNzky/4/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^            # match beginning of line
(?!          # begin negative lookahead
  .+         # match 1+ chars
  \b(\w+)\b  # match a word in cap grp 1
  .+         # match 1+ chars
  \b\1\b     # match the contents of cap grp 1 with word breaks
)            # end negative lookahead
(?:          # begin non-cap grp
  .+         # match 1+ chars
  \b\w+\b    # match a word
)            # end non-cap grp
{5}          # execute non-cap grp 5 times
.*           # match 0+ chars
[.?!]        # match a punctuation char
\s*          # match 0+ whitespaces
$            # match end of line
```

Comment: This is awesome Cary! Really appreciate the breakdown of what each bit does. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Items 1. and 3. are easily done by regex, but

`2. words in sequence must be distinct`

I don't see how you could do it with a regex pattern. Remember that regex is a string-matching operation; it doesn't do heavy logic. This problem doesn't sound like a regex problem to me.

I recommend splitting the string in the character `" "` and checking word by word. Quickier, no sweat.

**Edit**

2. can be done with a lookahead as [Cary said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61111356/5294876).

Comment: Amazing. I didn't know that!